# Creating a specific Sublime Text's snippet, using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, extjs, sublimetext3

## Context

I have a process that envolves creating similar file/filename structures that have inside of it the name of itself, and things like that, i do this every day, and i see that is repetitive and have a pattern, then i got the idea of creating a Sublime Text's Snippet to generate the code for me, adding a significant improvement on my performance.

## Example

There is a example of a **complete** "model" using the structure that i said:

```js
Ext.define('App.model.geral.layouts.Layouts', {
    extend: 'App.ux.model.base',

    fields: [
        { name: 'Foo', type: 'string', fieldLabel: 'Foo' },
        { name: 'Bar', type: 'int', fieldLabel: 'Bar' },
        { name: 'FooTwo', type: 'boolean', fieldLabel: 'FooTwo' },
        { name: 'Date', type: 'date', fieldLabel: 'Date' },
    ],
  
    proxy: Use.util.Model.getProxy({
        controller: 'Layouts'
    })
});
```

This is a simple and small sample of a file using mine structure. So that file,  following the patterns will be placed at `C:/Dev/Com/app/model/geral/layouts/Layouts.js`, because models, are inside the folder **model** and **geral** is the module that the entity **layouts** belong to.

## What i've tried

I tried various things and the most far i did go was that snippet file:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Ext.define('App.model.${TM_FILEPATH/.+(?:model\/)(.+)\.\w+/\l$1/}', {
    extend: '',

    fields: [ ],

    proxy: '' 
});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>mitem</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

When i trigger that snippet on a empty file named and located in: `C:/Dev/Com/app/model/geral/layouts/Layouts.js` (as the pattern), it results:

```js
Ext.define('App.model.geral/layouts/Layouts', {
    extend: '',

    fields: [ ],

    proxy: '' 
});
```

As you can see, i got `'App.model.geral/layouts/Layouts'` instead of `'App.model.geral.layouts.Layouts'` that is what i want. I am close to the final result that i want, as you can see on the complete model example, by the way i cannot go far than that, i dont have any knowledge of RegExp what i did was only researching and trying different things.

If helpful, there is a more complete info about Sublime Snippets that i found is:

```
$PARAM1 .. $PARAMn  Arguments passed to the insert_snippet command. (Not covered here.)
$SELECTION  The text that was selected when the snippet was triggered.
$TM_CURRENT_LINE    Content of the cursor’s line when the snippet was triggered.
$TM_CURRENT_WORD    Word under the cursor when the snippet was triggered.
$TM_FILENAME    Name of the file being edited, including extension.
$TM_FILEPATH    Path to the file being edited.
$TM_FULLNAME    User’s user name.
$TM_LINE_INDEX  Column where the snippet is being inserted, 0 based.
$TM_LINE_NUMBER Row where the snippet is being inserted, 1 based.
$TM_SELECTED_TEXT   An alias for $SELECTION.
$TM_SOFT_TABS   YES if translate_tabs_to_spaces is true, otherwise NO.
$TM_TAB_SIZE    Spaces per-tab (controlled by the tab_size option).
```

I used that info to get the filepath, i tried using another variables like filename but did not get that far.

That will be very useful if someone can help me to get to the final result.

Comment: I will add some bounty to the correct answer of that question, after 2 days from now. (bounty period gap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Ext.define('App.model.${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/model\/)|(\w+)|(\.\w+$)|(\/)/(?2$2)(?4.)/g}', {
    extend: '',

    fields: [ ],

    proxy: '' 
});
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>mitem</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Btw, I highly recommend installing the [PackageDev package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) if you haven't already, to get some syntax highlighting on the snippet and regular expression/replacement.
[image: how the snippet looks]

## How it works:

### Match:

- `(^.+\/model\/)` match from the beginning of the file path up to and including `/model/`, and store in capture group 1
- `|` or
- `(\w+)` match any sequence of word characters and store in capture group 2
- `|` or
- `(\.\w+$)` match the file extension and store in capture group 3
- `|` or
- `(\/)` match a `/` and store in capture group 4

### Replacement:

- `(?2$2)` if capture group 2 participated in the match, replace it with itself - i.e. keep it
- `(?4.)` if capture group 4 participated in the match, replace it with a dot

### Flags:

- `g` global modifier to match as many times as possible

Arguably you don't need the capture groups 1 and 3, but I included them to make it easier to tell what is being matched.

Comment: Great, that is what i want, btw with exactly your regex i got `App.model.geral.layouts.layouts` when what i want is `App.model.geral.layouts.Layouts`, so i removed that: `L$` and then i got the perfect result, you should change it on the answer

Comment: And what if i want `App.model.geral.layouts` only as result? i tried removing some things but nothing worked. (asking that because some files are specific).

Comment: so without the filename? you could change it to: `${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/model\/)|(\w+\.\w+$)|(\w+)|(\/)/$3(?4.)/g}`

Comment: that last one, barely worked, but it leaves a dot in the end the result was `App.geral.layouts.` i can obtain it without the last dot? damn i need to learn regex, you should recommend me some reference later kkk. the plugin i cant install yet because i dont have access to the url, but i am providing that :P

Comment: oh just add another `\.` before the `\w` like `${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/model\/)|(\.\w+\.\w+$)|(\w+)|(\/)/$3(?4.)/‌​g}`

Comment: unfortunately that one with the additional `\.` before the `\w` resulted me: `App.model.geral.‌​layouts.‌​Layouts.js` instead of `App.model.geral.layouts`

Comment: oh sorry, this is before it's been replaced, so it needs to be a `\/` instead of a `\.`: `${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/model\/)|(\/\w+\.\w+$)|(\w+)|(\/)/$3(?4.‌​)/‌​g}`

Comment: nice.. now it worked, but i still dont understand how hahah (sadly). And, the last thing that is missing to complete all the snippets i created is to get the foldername father of the file, with first letter capital, more easy to see: using the last regex you gave me, the bold part of it ONLY i want >> `App.model.geral.*layouts*` and with the first letter capital, resulting: `Layouts`. Thats because some filenames are not like this, are different, then i need to get the foldername with first letter capital. After that its all done, and i have to thank you after all. i'll +100 you in 19 hours :)

Comment: try `${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/model\/)|(\w+)(\/\w+\.\w+$)|(\w+)|(\/)/(?2\u$2)(?4$4)(?5.)/g}` :)

Comment: It didnt works, resulted `geral.Layouts` but i did used every percent of my brain to modify it and make it like this `${TM_FILEPATH/(^.+\/view\/)|(\w+)(\/\w+\.\w+$)|(\w+)|(\/)/(‌​?2\u$2)/g‌​}` and now it works perfectly resulting `Layouts` wow! see i learned some regex with all that conversation haha, thank you man. we're done.

Comment: maybe you can help me on another question similar to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47658947/2319589